# Counting/random int in while loop

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, integer

I want this while loop to change numbers with every iteration (both the count and random int.) but when I run the program, the loop just goes on with the same numbers on the count and random int.:

```
# if 4 sides 
die1 = random.randint(1,4)
die2 = random.randint(1,4)
count = 1 

while sides == 4 and die1 != die2:
    print (count, ". die number 1 is", die1, "and die number 2 is", die2,".")
    count == count + 1

print ("You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number", count,".")
```

Comment: Snake-eyes in dice games generally means a pair of ones, not just any pair.

Comment: To get rid of gratuitous whitespace in the output, consider `print("{}. Die number 1 is {} and die number 2 is {}.".format(count, die1, die2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the `random` calls also inside the `while` loop otherwise they will not change. And the other thing is that you compare `==` and not set `=` the counter:

```
import random

sides = 4
count = 1 
die1 = random.randint(1,4)
die2 = random.randint(1,4)

while sides == 4 and die1 != die2:
    print (count, ". die number 1 is", die1, "and die number 2 is", die2,".")
    count += 1
    die1 = random.randint(1,4)
    die2 = random.randint(1,4)

print ("You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number", count,".")
```

Trying a test run gives me:

```
1 . die number 1 is 4 and die number 2 is 3 .
2 . die number 1 is 2 and die number 2 is 1 .
3 . die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 2 .
4 . die number 1 is 3 and die number 2 is 4 .
5 . die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 4 .
You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number 6 .
```

One alternative that is almost identical but uses `break` instead of conditions on the while loop would be:

```
import random

sides = 4
count = 1 

def tossdie():
    """Function to create a random integer for a die"""
    return random.randint(1,4)

while True:
    die1 = tossdie()
    die2 = tossdie()
    print (count, ". die number 1 is", die1, "and die number 2 is", die2,".")
    if die1 == die2:
        break
    count += 1

print ("You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number", count,".")
```

Answer (score 4):

Each time you *call* `random.randint(1,4)`, you are creating a single random number. It does not magically change to a new random number whenever you print it.

Generate new random numbers with `random.randint(1, 4)` inside your `while` loop.

The second problem is that `count == count + 1` checks for equality (and returns `False` in your case). To do an assignment, use the assignment operator `=` or `count += 1` to increment `count` by one.

If you want a generator that endlessly spits out random numbers, write one:

```
>>> import random
>>> def rng(i, j):
...     while True:
...         yield random.randint(i, j)
... 
>>> random_gen = rng(1, 4)
>>> next(random_gen)
2
>>> next(random_gen)
3
>>> next(random_gen)
2
>>> next(random_gen)
2
>>> next(random_gen)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you needed the `sides` variable, so I left it out.
You want to roll the die in every loop, which means you have to re-assign `die1` and `die2` to a random number in each loop.

```
import random

# Initial parameters
die1 = random.randint(1,4)
die2 = random.randint(1,4)
count = 1

# Loop and roll die each time
while die1 != die2:
    print(count, ". die number 1 is", die1, "and die number 2 is", die2,".")
    die1 = random.randint(1,4)
    die2 = random.randint(1,4)
    count += 1

# Print on which die roll you got two equal die numbers rolled
print ("You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number", count,".")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop with `iter` to spit out pairs of random numbers , `enumerate` will do the counting, for snake-eyes you should also be checking that both are 1's not a random matching pair:

```
from random import randint                                                                   

def repeating_rand(i, j):                                                                    
    for count, (r1, r2 ) in enumerate(iter(lambda: (randint(i, j), randint(i, j)), None), 1):
        if r1 == 1 and r2 == 1:                                                              
            return "You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number {}.".format(count)            
        print("Try no. {}, die number 1 is {} and die number 2 is {}".format(count, r1, r2))
```

Output:

```
 In [12]: repeating_rand(1, 4)
Try no. 1, die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 2
Try no. 2, die number 1 is 4 and die number 2 is 1
Try no. 3, die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 2
Try no. 4, die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 3
Try no. 5, die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 3
Try no. 6, die number 1 is 3 and die number 2 is 4
Try no. 7, die number 1 is 4 and die number 2 is 2
Try no. 8, die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 2
Try no. 9, die number 1 is 3 and die number 2 is 2
Try no. 10, die number 1 is 4 and die number 2 is 3
Try no. 11, die number 1 is 1 and die number 2 is 3
Try no. 12, die number 1 is 3 and die number 2 is 4
Out[12]: 'You got snake eyes! Finally! On try number 13.'
```